# Rails Engines: How to generate a controller for Rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines, rails-generators

We have three Rails engines maintained in a single application. They are placed in `vendor` folder,

```
vendor/
   - Engine1
   - Engine2
   - Engine3
```

How can I generate controller for `Engine1` from my root folder as we normally create controllers? For example,

`> rails generate controller Engine1:users`

Note:- I could create controller by moving around the folders. That is move to `Engine1` folder from root app and generate controller, which works fine. But every time moving around from my root app and generating gets bit hard.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible, as the Rails generator does not have support for calling a generator in another Engine. It would have to do this since the Engine can be configured differently from the main Rails app, for example you engine might have:

```
# my_engine/lib/engine.rb

config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
end
```